# i2cdetect on Raspberry pi 4 shows different addresses everytime the command is entered

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi4

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi 4 to test different sensors. Right now I am trying to connect the DLVR-L05D-E1BD pressure sensor by All Sensors. My problem right now is that when I enter `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` in the command window to find the address, I get a bunch of addresses listed which changes everytime I enter the command. This continues until every address is shown in the table.

I also found out that if I remove the power or Vs connection from the sensor (so only SDA, SCL and ground are connected to the Pi) and then enter `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`, I get only one address (the expected one, 28).

To make sure nothing was wrong with the Pi I connected a particle sensor (Sensirion SPS30) and managed to detect it with the same command.

My code also sometimes manages to communicate with the pressure sensor while other times I get "Remote I/O error".

I've used two different units of the same model of pressure sensors and both have the same problem.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated!

EDIT: When I reboot the Pi, I still have the same problems, however after a while the addresses just keeps changing everytime I run `i2cdetect`, never converging at showing all addresses.

Comment: Your swap troubleshooting is good. I am sure you can soon find out the root cause by your self. My educated guess is that problem is related to hardware, ie wiring and PSU, and e xternal PSU, and short wires, few devices, should help. PS - I have more than 200 hours troubleshooting Rpi I2C stuff. You can search rpi.org.forum for over 100+ posts on my painful I2C experience. The following SO Q&A might also help: Raspberry Pi 4 I2C bus not working correctly - SO, 2020, Viewed 5k times
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757687/raspberry-pi-4-i2c-bus-not-working-correctly. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, I switched to shorter wires which fixed the problem where I would get different addresses each time I entered the command "sudo i2cdetect -y 1". It still doesn't show the right address, in fact it shows all possible addresses. I'm guessing something is wrong with the i2c unit after all.